# How to create a certificate for Digital Signature

Tags: asp.net, certificate, digital-signature, bouncycastle, digital-certificate

I working on digital signature and I'm using BouncyCastle library in c# but I don't understand how I'm going to create certificate?
Especially hmm server and client, how are they working together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is something like a self-signed certificate to do some testing, there are a few ways:

- Online web tools (http://www.makecert.com/tools/create-self-signed-ssl-certificate/default.aspx)
- Bouncy Castle itself (http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation)
- IIS has some tools to do this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(WS.10).aspx)
- OpenSSL

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question you're asking is then.  If it's a CA you're trying to setup, and you're on a MS platform, there might be some information in this link  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875810.aspx.  If not, then OpenSSL can also do that.